# Clean my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works fine (at least in the surface) but I'm concerned about how clean and simple is my jquery code. For example, I opened and closed my scripts three times and call the same function everywhere. I'm sure this is a little redundant, but I don't now how to simplify. Sorry, I'm a bit of a roockie. I would appreciate any help.

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
    jQuery("#input_3_4").keyup(function() {
        jQuery("#previewtxt1a").html(jQuery(this).val())
    })
});

jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
    jQuery("#input_3_5").keyup(function() {
        jQuery("#previewtxt2a").html(jQuery(this).val())
    })
});

jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){ 
    jQuery("#input_3_6").keyup(function() {
        jQuery("#previewtxt3a").html(jQuery(this).val())
    })
});
```

Comment: move your question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75433/guradio)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely refactor out the common code into a function:

```
function set(el) {
  jQuery("#previewtxt2a").html(jQuery(el).val())
  });
}
```

You also don't need to split out the multiple script blocks, indeed, your code could be a lot simpler:

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
    [
        {src: '#input_3_4', target: '#previewtxt1a'}, 
        {src: '#input_3_5', target: '#previewtxt2a'}, 
        {src: '#input_3_6', target: '#previewtxt3a'}
    ].forEach(function(item) {
        jQuery(item.src).keyup(function() {
            jQuery(item.target).html(this.val());
        });
    });
```

As a side-note, I'm not sure why people are voting this question down -- it's a question about refactoring from someone who wants to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more cleaner version of your code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$("#input_3_4").keyup(function () {
    jQuery("#previewtxt1a").html($(this).val())
});

$("#input_3_5").keyup(function () {
    $("#previewtxt2a").html($(this).val())
});


$("#input_3_6").keyup(function () {
    $("#previewtxt3a").html($(this).val())
});

});

</script>
```